# Recreating an openssl decrypt command in PyCrypto

Tags: python, openssl, aes, pycryptodome

I am trying to recreate the second command (decryption) in PyCrypto

```
openssl enc -aes-128-ecb -nosalt -base64 -pass pass:abcde -md sha256 -in test.txt -out out.txt
openssl enc -d -aes-128-ecb -nosalt -base64 -pass pass:abcde -md sha256 -in out.txt
```

Content of `test.txt` is `flag{flagflag}`. Output of encryption is `0KSF5koIceXxszsgzpl4uA==`.

`binascii.a2b_base64(b'0KSF5koIceXxszsgzpl4uA==')` produces the same bytearray as `openssl enc -aes-128-ecb -nosalt -pass pass:abcde -md sha256 -in test.txt -out out.txt` (no `-base64`), so I know base64 decoding should be the first step.

```
p = "abcde".encode()
h = SHA256.new(p)
key = h.hexdigest()[:32].upper()
```

`key` matches with the following output, so I know the key generation code is correct:

```
$ openssl enc -aes-128-ecb -nosalt -pass pass:abcde -base64 -md sha256 -in test.txt -v -P
key=36BBE50ED96841D10443BCB670D6554F
bufsize=8192
```

However, putting this all together produces garbage in `msg`. Any pointer in where I got it wrong would be appreciated.

```
from Crypto.Hash import SHA256
from Crypto.Cipher import AES

import binascii

c = binascii.a2b_base64(b'0KSF5koIceXxszsgzpl4uA==')

p = "abcde".encode()
h = SHA256.new(p)
key = h.hexdigest()[:32].upper()

cipher = AES.new(key.encode(), AES.MODE_ECB)
msg = cipher.decrypt(m)
print(msg)
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue: the key encoding is wrong: It is not encoding `key` to utf8 to get bytearray, it should be treating `key` as hex number and decode it to bytearray.

```
cipher = AES.new(bytearray.fromhex(key), AES.MODE_ECB)
msg = cipher.decrypt(m)
print(msg)
```